# How many Databases can be Attached to Sqlite Connection?

Tags: database, sqlite

I am refactoring my Sqlite Helper class in .NET, so that it supports attaching database and would like to know how many databases can be attached to the connection?

In http://sqlite.org it says the limit is SQLITE_LIMIT_ATTACHED but I could not find its default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [limits of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html), the default number is **10**.